# How to use one class in another class that is in the same package?

Tags: go, package

I'm fairly new to Go and I'm making an a small flashcards app.
My package structure is this

```
VocabHelper
|
-|src
--|com
---|wks
----|card
------Card.go
------Deck.go
----|main
------main.go
```

Deck and Card are two separate classes but they're in the same package:

**Card.go**

```
package card

type Card struct{

    Question string
    Answer string

}
```

**Deck.go**

```
package card

import (
    "math/rand"
)

type Deck struct{

    Cards []card.Card

}
```

When I try to compile the project, the compiler says `undefined:card` even though card is in the same package as deck. How can I use the card class in the deck class?

Comment: A few things you might want to keep in mind: Go doesn't have classes (this isn't just a pedantic terminology thing... you really shouldn't think of a struct like a class in Java or C#), there's no reason you couldn't combine these two files into one (though there's nothing wrong with having multiple files either) and I think its conventional to use lowercase file names...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. BTW: Is it necessary to make a New constructor or can I assume that the developer knows how to initialise Deck, for example.

Comment: Most packages provide some sort of New function, but if your struct is really simple it's not necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leave off the `card.` part, and it should work. They're both in the same package.

```
type Deck struct{
   Cards []Card
}
```